# starling big textField causes texture too big (max 2048x2048) error

Tags: textfield, starling-framework

Sorry for the noobie question but why does a textfield with the size of 1024x1024 cause this error when running on an ipad simulatation? It seems like the ipad only allows textfields to the size of 512x512, the iphone4 allows 1024x1024 and the iphone 3 allows 2048x2048, why is this?

I need to set the textfield to quite a large size since the game I'm making requires quite long words (which have to be on a single line) to be scaled to extremely large sizes. In order to make sure the largest scalable size is still sharp I initialised the font to a large size and scale it down upon loading so it always remains crisp.

Answer (score 0):

you better use according to your game width height. I hope if you are using starling you would have defined in your start file view port something. so define your game width height according to your device width height . so that you can assign textfield width and height to  GameWidth and GameHeight or if you require you can reduce using this GameWidth and GameHeight variables.